# How do I see which version of MVC is installed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I tell which version of MVC (i.e. MVC 2 Beta, MVC 2 RC) is installed on my machine?

Comment: best answers are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930217/which-version-of-mvc-am-i-using), hope helps someone.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless I got you wrong, checking the version displayed for System.Web.Mvc in your windows\assembly folder should help you.

Comment: ok I'm there, how do I tell if it's RC, beta 1, beta 2, RC2, release etc?

Comment: this lied to me for some reason. It said v2 after I just installed 3

Comment: What if the assembly reference is not available?

Comment: It's showing me 2.0.. while I'm working with MVC 4 :/

Answer (score 62):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET 
Inside this folder will be all versions of MVC that you have installed.
This is for Win 7.

Comment: this didnt worked for me, inside Microsoft ASP.NET folder, it shows ASP.NET MVC 4, but from the method mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930217/which-version-of-mvc-am-i-using) when i check System.Web.Mvc assembly definition in web.config and "References" folder in the solution explorer both show the exact version as `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />` so my version is MVC 5, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 26):

Look under Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs

Comment: In the Add/Remove Programs only have: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC3 while in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET folder have ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASP.NET MVC 4

Answer (score 24):

Simply looking in the Program Files(x86) isn't enough. If you've installed MVC5 for instance via NuGet, then you won't see a MVC5 folder under that folder. In my opinion, the most effective way of knowing which version of MVC you are using is to go to your VS project and look at the references under your main web application. Then find "System.Web.Mvc", right click, then click properties. You will see the version as a property. I tried to post an image of this but it won't allow me to do that; oh well, sorry I couldn't.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for in MVC 5, thanks

Comment: I would add that the Version property is located all the way at the bottom of the list and is not the Runtime Version which is also located in the properties window.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [MvcDiagnostics](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/05/asp-net-mvc-diagnostics-using-nuget.aspx/) tool, which is [available as a nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcDiagnostics)

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930239/678338) it is useful if you want to know what version of MVC your site is running.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET programs folder is the best place to look as it will show the versions in folders. To note though, if you installed Visual Studio 2012, then it installed both versions MVC3 and MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

You may have **several versions** of .NET installed on your machine. If you are using `Windows 10` this is how to find versions 1 through 4:

From the **Start** menu > choose **Run** > enter **Regedit** > select **Ok**. You must have *administrative* credentials to run **Regedit**.

In the **Registry Editor** open the following subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP

[image]

Find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#net_a). Also if you were wondering what the *latest version* of `.Net` is - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies) is a handy list.

Answer (score -1):

Ananize Scott, already give one version of the answer, I found folders MVC2 and MVC3 in folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web

"don't forget to set properties of mvc.dll to 'copy local true' if you are using older version of MVC than latest installed or it will not work.