# ASP.NET MVC error after deploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am starting with ASP.NET MVC development just now, after some years of ASP.NET WebForms.
Following a simple tutorial, I developed an HelloWorld ASP.NET MVC web site and deployed to the FileSystem using Visual Studio 2012 deployment tool: no problem to access it from my IIS.
I tried then FTP deployment to my Internet Service Provider (I just FTP-copied the files and folders contained in the FileSystem deployment made by VisualStudio). If I try to access the same site hosted by the ISP I get the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.TypeAccessException: Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Object)' to access type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.IDOUtils+SiteDelegate0>' failed.

Source Error:

Line 4:  
Line 5:  <h2>Indewx</h2>
Line 6:  <div>@Me.ViewBag.Message</div>


Source File: D:\Inetpub\webs\pgsoftwareit\Views\Home\Index.vbhtml    Line: 6
```

Any suggestion? Any params in the web.config to be tuned? Or problems with trust by the ISP?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do your ISP offers .NET MVC hosting? Keep in mind that not all .NET hosting sites do it.

Comment: As far as I know, it should. It is aruba.it and googling around I found other people using ASP.NET MVC and Aruba as ISP.

Comment: See if MVC is installed ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111936/how-do-i-see-which-version-of-mvc-is-installed

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div>@ViewBag.Message</div>
```

instead of

```
<div>@Me.ViewBag.Message</div>
```